# Open close toggle button. Hide first button when opened

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a open/close toggle and I'm trying to make the first button hide when it's toggled open and then reappear when it's closed.

Here's what I have:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".slider").hide('slow');

  jQuery(".clicker, .clicker2").click(function() {
    jQuery(".slider").toggle('slow');
    return false;
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clicker">CLICK HERE</button>
<div class="slider">
  Blah blah blah
  <a class="clicker2" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Change `jQuery(".slider").toggle('slow')` to `jQuery(".slider,.clicker").toggle('slow')`

Comment: Can you explain exactly what part you're having difficulty with?  You have code to handle a click event and you have code to *toggle* visibility, you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate `.clicker` & `.clicker2` click events. Then, toggle `.slider` and `.clicker` button.

**Here is Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".slider").hide('slow');

    jQuery(".clicker").click(function() {
      jQuery(".slider").toggle('slow');
      jQuery(this).toggle('slow');
      return false;
    });
    jQuery(".clicker2").click(function() {
      jQuery(".slider, .clicker").toggle('slow');
      return false;
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clicker">CLICK HERE</button>
<div class="slider">
  Blah blah blah
  <a class="clicker2" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have code to toggle based on clicking, so you can add the 'open' button to the toggle code in the same way as applying the click event to multiple elements:

```
jQuery(".slider,.clicker").toggle();
```

Updated snippet:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // hidden in the HTML to remove FOUC: jQuery(".slider").hide('slow');

  jQuery(".clicker, .clicker2").click(function() {
    jQuery(".slider,.clicker").toggle('slow');
    return false;
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clicker">CLICK HERE</button>
<div class="slider" style='display:none;'>
  Blah blah blah
  <a class="clicker2" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```